# Why does Visualforce inputField using html-disabled = false still disable the field?

Tags: visualforce, html, inputfield, conditional, disable

In my VF page I need to disable an inputField based on a boolean condition set in my controller. If I add the **html-disabled** option to the inputField it disables the field, regardless of what I set the value to (true or false). Only when I remove the **html-disabled** setting altogether, does it allow input.

```
<apex:inputField  html-disabled="{!IF(allowChoice, false , true)}" value="{!account.Preference__c}" html-placeholder="Select"/>
```

If **allowChoice** = true, I want the inputField to allow input (it's a picklist /dropdown). If it's false, I want to disallow selection. Problem is, regardless of what **allowChoice** is set to, it disables the field on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, by definition, if the HTML disabled attribute exists at all, the field is disabled. It's not a boolean.

I suppose you could put two consecutive instances of `<apex:inputField>`, one disabled with `rendered="{! !allowChoice}"` and the other enabled with `rendered="{!allowChoice}"`. That way VF will only ever render one of them at a time. Or make the read-only one an `<apex:outputField>`.

Comment: So how do I achieve what I'm trying to do then if I can't use this - do you have an alternative suggestion maybe please?

Comment: I suppose you could put two consecutive instances of `<apex:inputField>`, one disabled with `rendered="{! !allowChoice}"` and the other enabled with `rendered="{!allowChoice}"`. That way VF will only ever render one of them at a time. Or make the read-only one an `<apex:outputField>`.

Comment: I have done that - solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to hear. I added the comment to my answer.